# Не работает метод write()

Tags: python, python-3.x

при написании кода возникла данная ниже ошибка, причем после ввода любого сообщения просто выдается она. Желаемый результат - в текстовый файл должен записываться вводимый текст с новой строки, без потери старых.

```
with open("some.txt", "w") as ouf:
     ouf.write(input(), file=ouf)
     ouf.close()





\\\
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/python-projects/chat bot/chat-bot.py", line 2, in <module>
ouf.write(input(), file=ouf)
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: там должен быть этот file=ouf? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

Comment: не обязательно, нужно просто что бы выполнялась задача
> в текстовый файл должен записываться вводимый текст с новой строки, без потери старых

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
with open("some.txt", "a") as ouf:
     ouf.write(input()+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("some.txt", "w") as ouf:   
    ouf.write(input())
    ouf.close()
```

Все работает!